# XmlMapper не видит значение SOAP

Tags: java, xml, soap, jackson

есть респонсе soap

```
 <FindClientFLResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <FindClientFLResult>
        <Responses>
           <ResponseId>0</ResponseId>
           <RequestId>0</RequestId>
           <Result>1</Result>
           <HasErrors>false</HasErrors>
           <Errors />
        </Responses>
        <ClientId>1354133</ClientId>
        <ScroogeId />
        <Clients>
           <StateCode>4111111115</StateCode>
...
```

есть класс EntityDto

```
private boolean hasErrors;
private String clientId;
private String result;
private String code;
private String text;
```

с помощью XmlMapper перевожу в soap в EntityDto

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), EntityDto.class);
```

результат:

```
not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: "result", "hasErrors", "clientId", "code", "text"])
```

Подскажите почему не парсит в поле данные?

Comment: Может потому что надо использовать вместо `JsonProperty` `@XmlElement()` и у вас используется несколько объектов внутри `FindClientFLResponse`, а вы пытаетесь засунуть всё в рамках 1 объекта. Создайте для каждой вложенности отдельный объект, чтобы было что-то типа `FindClientFLResponse ->FindClientFLResult->Responses->Clients`

Comment: @Dred hasErrors парсит же, оно должно работать по принципу ObjectMapper'a c json

Comment: Тогда, видимо, потому что вы делаете `response.getBody()`. По факту, у вас тут вырванные куски кода, по которым сложно что-то сказать. `mapper /response ...`

Comment: UPD выяснил что оно вообще не парсит, "hasErrors = false" по умолчанию идет

Comment: попробуйте сначала на простой структуре сделать парсинг, где внутри объекта будет 1-2 элемента. После этого усложняйте задачу. Если это не получится, обновите весь вопрос предоставив [минимальные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) параметры